# how to implement pagination in html object in birt report with java code?

Tags: java, pagination, paging, birt

I want implement pagination navigation in birt report in html object using java api. as it shows in web viewer in birt report.in html object its not showing when opening in browser.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI6ck.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you are using the RE API (eg. RunTask/RenderTask/RunAndRenderTask).

I doubt this is possible with reasonable effort, but maybe you should look at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/120397/ and https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/119676/.

Why don't you use the viewer servlet if it gives you the functionality that you need?

Comment: Thanks to Reply. but still unable to see pagination. I am using HTMLRenderOption to get html object to view report in java api. by default in HTMLRenderOption navbar is disabled.